# How can I prevent a producer to receive a message sent to a topic?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ topics.
My applications create some topics, and create a producer and a consumer on theses topics.

When a producer send something, it will receive back the message because there is also a consumer on this topic in the same topic.

There is a topic dedicated for each application (different code, for different computer running it) and there is a main central core process that will join each topic to process messages, and will then reply to the topic where the request message have been posted.

Some topics are "general purpose" topics, where some messages won't have a reply, but that many process will take into account.

Is there something in ActiveMQ that can prevents the producer to receive back what it sends ?

Edit : please note that I am quite a newbie with ActiveMQ, I am using it not so long ago, and with very basic settings : no persistence, as simple application bus

Comment: I think that you need to clarify what are you calling producers and consumers in your context.

Comment: @Antoniossss Producer and consumer as in the ActiveMQ java API. The first is a way to send message, the send is used to receive messages

Comment: You explained something that everybody knows. What nobody knows is what is your consumer and producer and why are you presenting those as it would be one and the same entity. This can be separate process (differen machine eg), simple instances of some classes in same application etc.

Comment: @Antoniossss sorry, I have edited the question, hopping it is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [create your consumer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createConsumer(javax.jms.Destination,%20java.lang.String)) you can specify a [message selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html#bncer) to exclude messages with your producer's unique ID. Your producer can set its ID in a [message property](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setStringProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) when creating its messages.

Comment: Ho ! Great news, I am not currently in front of my code, but this seems to be exactly what I am searching ! Thanks.

Comment: So I can set an ID in a producer, and tell the consumer with a selector like "! the ID". Great.

Comment: don't worry, as soon I am able to test it, I will ;) thanks for the tips.